# WPF - Identifying a scroll event from a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbars

If you have a ListView with both horizontal and vertical scroll bars. How do you tell which one a scroll event is coming from?

ScrollBar.Scroll="xxx" doesn't seem to differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Oops Figured it out:

The original source of the routed event will be the scroll bar, just need to check its Orientation property.